# Python Threading Error when executing a MSSQL statement

Tags: python, sql-server, multithreading

I have a producer, consumer application where the producer reads a database and puts the results into a website. On success, The consumer then gets the id of the transaction and updates the db.

The program runs as required until it attempts to execute the update. It fails sometimes with this error 'HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!'

The code can comfortably write to file without any issues.

What could i do to fix this? We need to update the db.

Thanks
Notes...using python 2.7 with pyodbc on mssql 2008.

code below

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    from urlparse import urlparse
    from threading import Thread
    import httplib, sys
    import Queue
    import urllib2
    import urllib
    from time import localtime, strftime
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    from functions import Functions
    from pyodbcclass import db_mssql

    now = strftime("%y-%m-%d-%H%M%S", localtime())
    k = db_mssql()


    thread_list = []
    thread_list2 = []
    getFromDBQueue = Queue.Queue()
    updateDBQueue = Queue.Queue()
    number_of_consumer_threads = 3

    def putURL():
        querySql = "select distinct top 3 id,url from tblURL where processed=0  order by id asc"

        re = k.query2(querySql)
        if re:

            for r in re:
                id = r.id
                params = urllib.urlencode({'user': user, 'password': password})
                ourl = urlini + "?%s" % params
                urlplusid = {'url':ourl.strip(),'id':id}
                getFromDBQueue.put(urlplusid)

    def getURL(thread_id):
        while 1:
            try:
                URL_toget = getFromDBQueue.get(block=False)
                url2 = URL_toget['url']
                msgid2 = URL_toget['id']
            except Queue.Empty:
                print "thread exiting, id: " + str(thread_id) + "++getFromDB++"
                sys.exit()
            status,url = getStatus(url2)
            if status == 200:
                updateDBQueue.put(msgid2)

            print(status)

    def updateDB(thread_id):
        while 1:
            try:

                id2 = updateDBQueue.get(block=False)
                if id2:
                    params = ['true',id2]
                    sqlupdate = "UPDATE tblURL SET processed=? WHERE id=?"
                    k.execute3(sqlupdate,params)

            except Queue.Empty:
                print "thread exiting, id: " + str(thread_id) + "**update**"
                sys.exit()


    # fill the queue with work and block until we are done filling the queue

    producer_thread = Thread(target=putURL)
    producer_thread.start()
    producer_thread.join()

    # we can now start consumers

    for i in range(number_of_consumer_threads):
        getfromDB = Thread(target=getURL, args=(i,))
        getfromDB.start()
        thread_list.append(getfromDB)


    for i in range(number_of_consumer_threads):
        update = Thread(target=updateDB, args=(i,))
        update.start()
        thread_list2.append(update)


    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.join()

    for thread2 in thread_list2:
        thread2.join()
```

Comment: [Apparently](http://pyodbc.googlecode.com/git-history/c3f6b46d8a4f73722439b4755ef5df42adff81d9/web/docs.html) you cannot share connections safely between different threads (at least not if used concurrently).

Comment: thanks christian...as long as i have only one thread running for update, it seems to work fine.